# How to filter only subdocuments corresponding to a request in mongoose

Tags: mongoose

I have hierarchical document in mongodb with two levels.
collection name is called book and it have author and author have diplome as sub document like this :

```
const bookSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    name: String,
    authors: [{
        authorName : String,
        diplomes :[{
             diplomeName: Strig,
             school: String
        }]
}],

})
module.exports = mongoose.model('book', bookSchema);


[ 
   { 
      "name":"name1",
      "authors":[ 
         { 
            "authorName":"authirname1-1",
            "diplomes":[ 
               { 
                  "diplomeName":"diplomename1-1-1",
                  "school":"school1-1-1"
               },
               { 
                  "diplomeName":"diplomename1-1-2",
                  "school":"school1-1-2"
               }
            ]
         },
         { 
            "authorName":"authirname1-2",
            "diplomes":[ 
               { 
                  "diplomeName":"diplomename1-2-1",
                  "school":"school1-1-1"
               },
               { 
                  "diplomeName":"diplomename1-2-2",
                  "school":"school1-2-2"
               }
            ]
         },

      ]
   },
   { 
      "name":"name2",
      "authors":[ 
         { 
            "authorName":"authirname2-1",
            "diplomes":[ 
               { 
                  "diplomeName":"diplomename2-1-1",
                  "school":"school2-1-1"
               },
               { 
                  "diplomeName":"diplomename2-1-2",
                  "school":"school2-1-2"
               }
            ]
         },
         { 
            "authorName":"authirname2-2",
            "diplomes":[ 
               { 
                  "diplomeName":"diplomename2-2-1",
                  "school":"school2-1-1"
               },
               { 
                  "diplomeName":"diplomename2-2-2",
                  "school":"school2-2-2"
               }
            ]
         },

      ]
   }
]
```

I want te return book with only school equal to school1-2-2
rsult expected is as follow :

```
[ 
   { 
      "name":"name1",
      "authors":[ 
         { 
            "authorName":"authirname1-2",
            "diplomes":[ 
               { 
                  "diplomeName":"diplomename1-2-2",
                  "school":"school1-2-2"
               }
            ]
         }
      ]
   }
]
```

please any help to get it work
need to use find method or aggregate ?

Answer (score 0):

We can use positional $[] operator to retrieve such kind of data but $[] operator is not allowed to search data 2 levels deep and this is your case you want to search data in 2 level deep array. please refer to [Documentation](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/positional-all/) for further concerns